# How to route a details page of a photo when clicked in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a react component which returns some photos that i got from an API. What i want is, when i click to a particular photo, i want to go to a details page ,and not see the other photos around the clicked one.for each different photo, i want to go to the ***url '/photoId'*** and i want that url doesn't include anything except the details page. think it like amazon shopping. in the browsing page you see a lot of different products,but when you click them, you go to a details page and don't see other products anymore. you see price, reviews etc in that detail page. that is what i want to do.
here is the code that i use for routing right now. characters is an array that i fetched from api.
And Detail  is the component that takes a character prop and returns details about it.
***Currently , when i clicked a photo, i see the details but i see other products too. How to fix it?***

in the normal flow of the page , page looks like this right now:[normal flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPrW3.png)

but when i click to a button, it looks like this:[clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dICcC.png)

Thanks for help.

```
<ul>
    {characters.map(x =>
      <li>

        <Link to={`/${x.id}`} >
          <div className='profile'>
            <img className='profileImage' src={x.image} />
            <div className='profileName'></div>{x.name}

          </div>
        </Link>


        <Route exact path={`/${x.id}`} component={() => <Detail character={x} />} >

        </Route>
      </li>)}
  </ul>
```

Comment: A `Route` component is essentially just a sophisticated regex test - wherever you place it is where the routed JSX is going to show up when the test matches the url. You need to restructure your routes so that `/` (or wherever this code sample is) and `/:id` are on different views. Your `Detail` view needs to be able to infer the character data based on the route `:id` used to reach it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working snippet that mimics your additional code sample - the `Switch` shouldn't actually be necessary but it doesn't work properly without it in Stack Snippets for some reason.

I also added in some basic state and paramater validation to demonstrate how to control routing when you can't pass the character data directly from the link, like your were trying to do in your original example.

I'd recommend looking over any unfamiliar aspects of the api at the [react router docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start).

```js
const { useState } = React; 
const { BrowserRouter, Route, Link, Redirect, Switch } = window.ReactRouterDOM;

const Detail = ({ name }) => {
  return <h2>{name}</h2>;
};

const App = () => {
  const [characters] = useState([
    { name: "rick" }, { name: "morty" }
  ]);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Link to="/rick">go to rick</Link>
          <Link to="/morty">go to morty</Link>
          <Link to="/summer">go to summer</Link>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/:id" render={(routeProps) => {
            const id = routeProps.match.params.id;
            const exists = characters.find((char) => char.name === id);

            if (exists) return <Detail name={exists.name} />;
            return <Redirect to="/" />;
          }}
        />
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/5.0.1/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: firstly,i am sorry that i asked from answer section, i am new to stackoverflow. and thank you so much for your answer,it works great.